# use actionscript press enter on the keyboard to submit form

Tags: actionscript-3, textinput, enter

When the user enters content in the Inputfields and presses the enter button on the keyboard how do you capture the KeyboardEvent for the user to login?

I think I know the first part of the code...
txt_inputOne.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler);

function keyHandler(event:Keyboardevent):void{
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)

After this i am confused on what to do. To submit a form pressing the enter button would i be required to give the value of the textinputs? 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event listener to the input fields.

- For the TextField:

  ```
  textField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);
  function handler(event:KeyboardEvent){
     // if the key is ENTER
     if(event.charCode == 13){
     // your code here
     // use textField.text to get the value
     }
  }
  ```
- For the TextInput:

  ```
  textInput.addEventListener(ComponentEvent.ENTER, listenerMethod);
  function handler(e:ComponentEvent):void{
          // your code here
          // use textInput.text to get the value
  }
  ```